# Parallelize custom function

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I've created a loop containing a matrix that works fine. The function tkas a matrix and as imput, calcualte correlation between the amtrix columns and then saves the output in the specified folde.r

```
mtx <- is a matrix file
out <- output folder
methods <- c("pearson","spearman","kendall")
for(method in methods){
drugCorrelations(methods,mtx,out.folder)
}
```

But I've not been able to parallelize it, this is my best try

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(3)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% {
  drugCorrelations(methods[i],mtx,out.folder)
}
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Any suggestion on how to parelleize this. I would prefer to keep the function as it is and being able to execute this function three times with the different methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has not worked in your attempt so far? See the code below for a working example using `mclapply`:

```r
library(parallel)
mclapply(
  methods,
  function(method) cor(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), method=method),
  mc.cores = 3
)
```

Comment: In your case, it might be `function(method) drugCorrelations(method, mtx, out.folder)` instead of my cor example

Comment: Thanks, I've give it a try and it seems to be working fine, now I'm goin to how is it working.

Thanks